# Task Scheduler is not connecting to web site

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, task

I have a script I wrote that will go to a website and download data to a csv. Then it will open into pandas dataframes a and sort the data which will be saved to HTML and emailed.

```
import csv
import requests
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# code to calculate the date parameters for pulling in wex data
date = {}
today = datetime.today()
end_day_delta = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
start_day_delta = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=5)
date['today'] = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=5)
date['yesterday'] = yesterday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
end_year = date['end_year'] = end_day_delta.strftime("%Y")
end_month = date['end_month'] = end_day_delta.strftime("%m")
end_day = date['end_day'] = today.strftime("%d")
start_year = date['start_year'] = start_day_delta.strftime("%Y")
start_month = date['start_month'] = start_day_delta.strftime("%m")
start_day = date['start_day'] = start_day_delta.strftime("%d")

# open a connection to wex and download data to csv files
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://www.wexonline.com/fleetpilot/main/fork_logon.cfm'
    user_name = 'my_user_name'
    pass_word = 'my_password'
    c.get(url)
    cfttoken = c.cookies['CFTOKEN']
    login_data = dict(csrfmiddlewaretoken=cfttoken, login_id=user_name,
                      pword_id=pass_word)
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={'Referer':
                     'https://www.wexonline.com/fleetpilot/main/logon.cfm'})
    url1 = 'https://www.wexonline.com/fleetpilot/query/VehicleDownload.cfm?
    page1 = c.get(url1)
    file = 'card_data.csv'
    with open(file, 'w') as temp_file:
        temp_file.writelines(page1.text)
    url2 = 'https://www.wexonline.com/fleetpilot/query/DriverDownload.cfm?
    page2 = c.get(url2)
    file = 'driver_data.csv'
    with open(file, 'w') as temp_file:
        temp_file.writelines(page2.text)
    urla = 'https://www.wexonline.com/fleetpilot/query/TransactionDownload.cfm?
    parm= 'more params'
    urlb = '%2F'
    urlc = '%2F'
    urld = 'ugly url'
    urle = '%2F'
    urlf = '%2F'
    urlg = 'ugly url'
    page3 = c.get(urla + start_month + urlb + start_day + urlc + start_year + \
              urld + end_month + urle + end_day + urlf + end_year + urlg)
    file = 'fuel_data.csv'
    with open(file, 'w') as temp_file:
        temp_file.writelines(page3.text)
# more code below
```

Please ignore the non-pythonic nature of the code. The first goal was to get something coded that worked (still have a ways to go) and then learn how to make it more pythonic. Also the urls need to be encoded. Where you see 'ugly code' I put that because the url is really long and just made things harder to read here.

Steps the program should take:

1. Log in to the website
2. download 3 datasets
3. save these to csv
4. open these 3 datasets into pandas dataframes
5. open a static dataset
6. merge, filter and save these datasets to html
7. email the html

When I rum with Windows 10 task scheduler it doesn't perform step 3. It may not perform step 2 either.

Here are the Task Scheduler settings
[image]
[image]

I have only been programming for a couple months so I am not sure about how to even troubleshoot the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of playing with the code,cleaning it up and tweaking with different settings I discovered that windows is saving the files to a different folder.

I had set the script to save the files to the working directory (where the python file was that I was running. C:\Users\dmckim.EVS\

```
file = 'fuel_data.csv'
with open(file, 'w') as temp_file:
    temp_file.writelines(page3.text)
```

It would work correctly when run from the command line but when run from Windows 10 Task Scheduler it would actually save the file to C:/Windows/System32/

I still don't know the reason for this but I have changed the file locations to show an absolute path like this:

```
file = r'C:\Users\dmckim.EVS\fuel_data.csv'
with open(file, 'w') as temp_file:
    temp_file.writelines(page3.text)
```

Now everything works correctly. I hope this helps someone else.